# Swift: Is it possible to pass a static property of another class to a method?

Tags: swift, function, methods, syntax

I have the following method that will download data from CloudKit and once done assign it a user default property.

```
private static func download<T>(dataType: T, recordID: CKRecord.ID, completion: (@escaping () -> Void)?) {
    database.fetch(withRecordID: recordID) { record, error in
        if let record = record, error == nil {
            print("\(recordID) downloaded from iCloud")
            guard let data = record["file"] as? Data else { return }
            guard let decoded = try? JSONDecoder().decode(dataType.self, from: data) else { return }
            // Assign to UserDefaults here
            completion()
        } else {
            print("Couldn't download \(recordID) \(error.debugDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is UserDefaults is handled by another class with a few properties with their own getters and setters. Is it still possible to have this generic method for downloading and have a parameter that is used to tell it which property of the Storage class it should assign the decoded data to? If not I was thinking I could have a switch statement based on the dataType. Thanks in advance.

```
class Storage {

static var ud = UserDefaults.standard
    
class var zones: [Zone] {
    get {
        if let data = ud.object(forKey: "zones") as? Data {
            do { return try JSONDecoder().decode([Zone].self, from: data) }
            catch { return ZoneHandler.defaultZones }
        } else { return ZoneHandler.defaultZones }
    }
    set {
        guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(newValue) else { return }
        ud.set(data, forKey: "zones")
        sharedStorage?.set(data, forKey: "zones")
    }
}

class var preferences: Preferences {
    get {
        if let data = ud.object(forKey: "preferences") as? Data {
            do { return try JSONDecoder().decode(Preferences.self, from: data) }
            catch { return Preferences() }
        } else { return Preferences() }
    }
    set {
        guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(newValue) else { return }
        ud.set(data, forKey: "preferences")
        sharedStorage?.set(data, forKey: "preferences")
    }
}

// Several more properties like this exist in this class 

}
```

Comment: Pass the decoded json to your completion handler, that’s what it’s supposed to be used for.

Comment: Thanks @JoakimDanielson, that's a good idea.

Comment: Post this as an answer and I'll accept it. Also, can I ask one more thing? I noticed that the download method doesn't actually compile with what I wrote here, it's saying Cannot convert value of type 'T' to expected argument type 'T.Type'. Do you know how to pass a type as a property? @JoakimDanielson Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use your completion handler to return the decoded result and then  handle any further logic in there. Furthermore, you don't need the dataType property, you can implicitly tell the compiler what T is when calling the function and also since you are decoding then T must conform to the Decodable protocol.

```
private static func download<T: Decodable>(recordID: CKRecord.ID, completion: @escaping (T?, Error?) -> Void) {
    database.fetch(withRecordID: recordID) { record, error in
        if let record = record, error == nil {
            print("\(recordID) downloaded from iCloud")
            guard let data = record["file"] as? Data else { return }
            guard let decoded = try? JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data) else { return }
            // Assign to UserDefaults here
            completion(decoded, nil)
        } else {
            print("Couldn't download \(recordID) \(error.debugDescription)")
            completion(nil, error)
        }
    }
}
```

Example use case

```
struct X: Codable {
    //...
}

download(recordID: someRecordId) { (record: X?, error) in
    if let x = record {
        Storage.preference = x
    }
}
```

You could also look into using `Result` when declaring your completion handler, `@escaping (Result<T, Error>) -> Void` but I leave that for you to research